# Who creates instances I inject mocks into: Mockito or Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing

I tried to test this:

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.dao.RoleDao;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {
    private final RoleDao roleDao;

    public RoleServiceImpl(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Role getRoleByName(String name) {
        return roleDao.findByAuthority(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Role> getAdminRoleSet() {
        return new HashSet<>(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN"));
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class RoleServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    @Mock
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER)).thenReturn(new Role(USER));
        when(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN))
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
    }

    @Test
    void getRoleByName() {
        assertThat(roleService.getRoleByName(USER)).extracting(Role::getAuthority).isEqualTo(USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthority(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void getAdminRoleSet() {
        var adminRoles = roleService.getAdminRoleSet().stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(adminRoles.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(adminRoles).asList().contains(ADMIN, USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

It passes, but there's something wrong. For instance, notice I didn't explicitly autowire test fields. Nevertheless, I didn't get any NPEs. **1) How was `RoleServiceImpl` obtained then?** Since I didn't autowire anything, not explicity at least, it seems it was created by Mockito using a regular `new` (as opposed to being received from a Spring container). However, if I remove `@SpringBootTest`, I start to get NPEs. **2) Does `@SpringBootTest` implicitly autowire my fields?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388593/22186847) may be useful, but doesn't address the questions I have

Comment: "How was RoleServiceImpl obtained then?" Do you noticed any particular annotation on that field?

Comment: You want to switch to `@MockBean` and `@Autowire` so less questions will be asked in the future.

Comment: Spring Boot enables support for Mockito, so mockito. However this test doesn't make sense and would work the same with a simple `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead and it would run much faster as well.

Comment: @Antoniossss actually, that would be less preferable since it's a unit test. I don't want my service test to fail just because the DAO is acting up

Comment: @Michael `@InjectMocks` doesn't tell me who creates the instance

Comment: @JoreJoh no it is not, it is `@springboot` test and as such it is far from unit. (unless something changed that I am not aware of)

Comment: @M.Deinum `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` gives an exception: `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at pp.spring_bootstrap.service.RoleServiceImplTest.setUp(RoleServiceImplTest.java:29)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.`

Comment: @Antoniossss I understand what you mean, but the purpose of the test is to test the service. I haven't removed `@SpringBootTest` because the test doesn't work without it

Comment: "*@InjectMocks doesn't tell me who creates the instance*" Please, read the linked question. "**@InjectMocks creates an instance of the class**"

Comment: Remove `SpringBootTest` and run it as plain junit tests if you want it to be real unit test(with Mockito extension so test actually will care about your mockito annotattion). Otherwise it will try to boot full spring context which you will not even use.

Comment: @Michael then why doesn't it work without the annotation? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141282/unnecessarystubbingexception-unnecessary-stubbings-detected) for more info

Comment: @Antoniossss I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77141282/unnecessarystubbingexception-unnecessary-stubbings-detected)

Comment: And you have unused stubbing excetpion which is "fine" in terms of this post.

Comment: The error from mockito is due to setting to much behavior which isn't used. Spring Boot will by default create lenient mocks (it configures mockito that way) which doesn't throw an exception.