# UnnecessaryStubbingException: Unnecessary stubbings detected

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I tried to test this:

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.dao.RoleDao;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {
    private final RoleDao roleDao;

    public RoleServiceImpl(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Role getRoleByName(String name) {
        return roleDao.findByAuthority(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Role> getAdminRoleSet() {
        return new HashSet<>(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN"));
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RoleServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    @Mock
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER)).thenReturn(new Role(USER));
        when(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN))
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
    }

    @Test
    void getRoleByName() {
        assertThat(roleService.getRoleByName(USER)).extracting(Role::getAuthority).isEqualTo(USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthority(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void getAdminRoleSet() {
        var adminRoles = roleService.getAdminRoleSet().stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(adminRoles.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(adminRoles).asList().contains(ADMIN, USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

The tests don't pass due to this exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at pp.spring_bootstrap.service.RoleServiceImplTest.setUp(RoleServiceImplTest.java:29)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

Line 29 is the first `when()` invocation:

```java
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER)).thenReturn(new Role(USER)); // this is line 29
        when(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN))
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
    }
```

I don't see anything unnecessary about it since it's required for the `getRoleByName()` test. As you may see in the code snippet, the class method indeed invokes it

What is the reason for this unusual behavior and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: It is only necessary in the second test  not in the first test. So move the stubbing to the related tests

Comment: The way the unnecessary stubbing detection works is by, for each test case, calculating which stubbings were provided and which were required. If those 2 things are different, it will throw. You seem to be under the impression that Mockito should understand which stubbings were specifically provided in `setup`, and consider them separately. I suppose it could do that, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stubbings are only related to one of both tests, so for the otherone is unneccesary, thats why you get the error.
So move the stubbing to the related tests or use `@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RoleServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    @Mock
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @Test
    void getRoleByName() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER)).thenReturn(new Role(USER));
        assertThat(roleService.getRoleByName(USER)).extracting(Role::getAuthority).isEqualTo(USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthority(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void getAdminRoleSet() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN))
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
        var adminRoles = roleService.getAdminRoleSet().stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(adminRoles.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(adminRoles).asList().contains(ADMIN, USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

or

```
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class RoleServiceImplTest {
```

Comment: Thank you! But why is Mockito making such a big deal out of "unused stubbings"?

Comment: I guess, "unused stubbing" makes it very hard to read the tests

Comment: Also, why does it work if I simply replace `@ExtendsWith` with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: I gues in spring they use the lenient approach see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19383